# Can we do virus scan on a file what gets uploaded via a portal in IBM Cloud(Bluemix)

Tags: java, cloud, ibm-cloud, virus-scanning

Can we do virus scan on a file that gets uploaded via a portal in IBM Cloud(Bluemix). If so in there a feature provided by Docker or any other component.

The Devops team is not able to figure out any available soultion/feature which can help in the scan, is it possible to do the scan via Code or if we can do it in cloud what would be the approach.

Comment: What is the overall scenario? Which runtime are you using?

Comment: I have a functionality to be developed, the user is allowed to upload different types of files or reports via the portal, example: Electricity bill, house receipt and children's school receipt. The file uploaded has to be scanned in order to avoid any type of issues.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Cloud does not offer a virus scanner for files, but have vulnerability scanner for containers and more. What you are looking for is custom functionality. You can either integrate it into your applications or utilize standard anti-virus software and deploy it and then invoke it on the file.

Comment: I am doing containers vulneraboility scan, but i was informed that there are some other features available in IBM Cloud that can scan through and scan the request. I will then integrate some available Java related available jars to have it scanned.